# Set list of Parse objects to select tag with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I have an `Angularjs` controller that gets `Parse` objects:

```
function MyController() {
    var self = this;
    var listObjects;

    function getObjects() {
        var myObject = Parse.Object.extend("MyObject");
        var query = new Parse.Query(myObject);

        query.find().then(function(objects) {
            for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                var object = objects[i];
                self.listObjects.push(object);
            }
        }, function(error) {
          console.log("ERROR: " + error);
        });
    }

    getObjects();

    self.getObjects = getObjects;
}
```

and I'm trying to set that list of objects to a `<select>` using:

```
<select ng-options="object.Name for object in myController.listObjects"></select>
```

My problem is, `listObjects` does not seem to be accessible in my `function`. If I do a `console.log()` on my `listObjects` in my function, it comes back as undefined. Is there a way to populate my `select` when the page loads? I also tried calling my function from an `onLoad` and that did not work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: where is categories coming from?

Comment: `var listObjects = [];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not making listObjects an array (or anything) and therefore it is undefined.

Change

```
var listObjects;
```

To

```
var listObjects = [];
```

and now you have access to the array.prototype methods, etc.

JsFiddle demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/0bmd2rxd/

Comment: This did not work, I'm still getting an error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.listObjects.push')`

Comment: self.listObjects is different than var = listObjects. Either use self in both places or not at all. http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to define shared objects within the scope of the controller.

`$scope.listObjects = ....`

then you can do

```
<select ng-options="object.Name for object in listObjects track by object.id"></select>
```

this will generate for each object in listObject an `<option>` tag like

```
<option value="value got from object.id">object.Name</option>
```

---

Another way of ding this is using ng-repeat on the option tag as follows

```
<select>
   <option ng-repeat="object in listObjects" value="{{object.id}}">{{object.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

You also need to define your listObjects inside the $scope of the controller.

Comment: There are other ways of using controllers. There is also something called  the "controller as" syntax. http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: I'm actually setting the `controller` in a `config` which is why I'm not specifying `controller as` in my html

Comment: Ok makes sense then. I have never used the controller as sytanx as @ChrisL pointed out. It is clear now that the problem is that you are pushing objects to an undefined variable.